# MSAccess Query Against Multivalued Field with Bogus Condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a report in Microsoft Access that allows a user to select a variety of criteria from a form (including the option to not select any options for a specific criteria, resulting in no restriction on that field), which are then used as criteria in the record source on the report. I have been successful in doing so with all but two of my criteria, which are querying against multi-valued fields (The user selects a single option from the combobox, but the table being queried allows for multiple values in the field).
The control source for my combobox ("OSHA Carcinogens") is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    TblCarcinogens.ID, 
    TblCarcinogens.[Carcinogen Name] 
FROM TblCarcinogens 
UNION 
SELECT
    Null AS AllChoice, 
    "(All)" AS Bogus 
FROM TblCarcinogens
ORDER BY TblCarcinogens.[ID];
```

The relevant code from my where clause is as follows:

```
((IIf([Forms]![FrmRPIFilters]![OSHA Carcinogens] Is Not Null,
    [RPIMaster].OSHA Carcinogens].[Value]=
        [Forms]![FrmRPIFilters]![OSHA Carcinogens],
    [RPIMaster].[OSHA Carcinogens].[Value]=
        [RPIMaster].[OSHA Carcinogens].[Value]))
<>False));
```

This method seems to work for anything other than multi-valued fields, but also seems pretty convoluted. I'm open to suggestions about streamlining the where clause in general as well if there is a better way to do it.

When the query is run with an option selected in the OSHA Carcinogens field on FrmRPIFilters, the result set includes only records which have no value stored in this field.

Does anyone have experience with this type of where clause and know what I'm missing?

Comment: I tend to follow MVPs advice (like Allen Browne) and stay away from those multi-valued fields.

Comment: I also never use multi-value but see if this helps you https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6F64F92D-659F-411C-9503-B6624E1E323A#bm4_6